# Вывод записей из БД автоматически

Tags: php, html, mysql, база-данных

У меня есть две кнопки, при нажатии на которые идет вывод постов из БД (с сортировкой).

**HTML код**:

```
<form method="POST">
    <input type="submit" name="newposts" value="Новые посты"></br></br>
    <input type="submit" name="oldposts" value="Старые посты"></br></br>
</form>
```

**PHP код**:

```
<?php

 if( isset( $_POST['newposts'] ) )
    {
       $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM data ORDER BY date1 DESC;") or die(mysql_error());
     $data = mysql_fetch_array($result);
     do {
         printf('
         </br>
         <div style="margin-left: 20px;">
            <i style="font-weight:700">%s</i>
            <p>%s</p>
            <p>%s</p>
            <p>%s</p>
            <p>Дата: %s</p>
            <hr>
        </div>
     ', $data["title"],$data["author"], $data["img1"], $data["descr"], $data["date1"]);
     }
     while($data = mysql_fetch_array($result));
    }

    if( isset( $_POST['oldposts'] ) )
    {
       $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM data ORDER BY date1 ASC;") or die(mysql_error());
     $data = mysql_fetch_array($result);
     do {
         printf('
         </br>
         <div style="margin-left: 20px;">
            <i style="font-weight:700">%s</i>
            <p>%s</p>
            <p>%s</p>
            <p>%s</p>
            <p>Дата: %s</p>
            <hr>
        </div>
     ', $data["title"],$data["author"], $data["img1"], $data["descr"], $data["date1"]);
     }
     while($data = mysql_fetch_array($result));
    }
     ?>
```

Хочу сделать так, что-бы при открытии страницы были сразу выведены новые посты, а не только при нажатии кнопки "Новые посты".

Искал атрибут для кнопок, типа activated или что-то в этом духе, но не нашел. Если вставить вывод над оператором условия, то при нажатии кнопок посты дублируются, этого мне не надо).

В этом деле совсем недавно, буду благодарен если поможете

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Например просто заменить

```
if( isset( $_POST['newposts'] ) )
```

на

```
if( !$_POST['oldposts'] )
```

тогда если не запросили старые посты будут выдаваться новые

Comment: Спасибо! Все работает, я добавил еще одну кнопку => с помощью логич. оператора сделал так: if( !$_POST['oldposts'] && !$_POST['knopka']), но если у меня таких кнопок будет очень много для сортировки, прийдеться добавлять очень много && (операторов), как можно это дело сократить, тк условие будет огромным?)

Comment: Наверное тогда просто if( !$_POST ), а далее для каждой кнопки свой if

Comment: @ArtemTereshkin, ну а по уму если писать код то если уж не на классах то хотя бы на функциях не повторяя каждый раз в if'ах идентичные коды типа printf/mysql_query и т.п.

Comment: Я вас понял, спасибо)